# no output error in hspice

Tags: ac, analysis, hspice

I have this code for hspice simulation

```
q3 simulation

vs      vin     0       ac      1       0
r1      vin     va      2k
r2      va      vb      2k
r3      vb      0       4k
r4      vb      vout    8k
e1      vout    0       0       va      2e5

.AC     DEC     50      100     100k    
.end
```

but it resulted in this error

```
**warning** no ac outputs specified, analysis omitted
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `.probe` or `.print` can solve this problem.

for example:

```
.probe v(vout)
```

OR

```
.print v(vout)
```